# Python TLS communication without sockets

Tags: python, tls1.3

We are using embedded devices connected via USB. Recently, TLS encyption was added to this, eventhough there is no IP. This is done with WolfSSL, which allows to redirect all the TLS reads and writes to our USB layer.
I now have to add a Python based test app into this picture. The problem I am facing is that the SSL module in Python3 seems coupled with the socket module, e.g. via the wrap_socket method.
I guess what I need is to be able to use the SSL module without the socket module....or to substiture the socket module with a "dummy" socket module, that the ssl would be happy to do the wrap_socket() on, but where I would have access to the read/write functions, and that would not depend on IP.

Thanks for any ideas/pointers. Paul.

( I do not have anything to show, as I am currently stuck )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First idea that comes to mind is to create a class that implements the `io.RawIOBase` interface. This interface defines the `readinto()` and `write()` methods that the `ssl` module expects from a socket-like object:

```py
import io

class USBTransport(io.RawIOBase):
    def __init__(self, usb_device):
        self.usb_device = usb_device

    def readinto(self, b):
        # Read from your USB layer here and fill the buffer `b`
        # ...
        return len(b)

    def write(self, b):
        # Write to your USB layer here
        # ...
        return len(b)
```

You can then use this `USBTransport` class to wrap your USB communication with TLS encryption by passing it to the `ssl.wrap_socket()` method:

```py
import ssl

usb_transport = USBTransport(usb_device)
ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(usb_transport, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
```

Comment: Thank you, Anton.
There is a little more the ssl.wrap_socket() needs from the "socket" being passed in. First error is a call to        if sock.getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE) != SOCK_STREAM:

I guess I can try to go down this path and add methods to the USBTransport class as needed.....unless there is already some "dummy" socket implementation, which already does all of this.